# Vuex - How to handle large Data-Sets (Individual Load of Items)

Tags: vuex

Lets say we have a set of items, that is thousands of entries long.
It would not be practical to load all of them on page-load and have it in the store. How exactly would you deal with this?

Would you just add items to the store, that are actually requested?
What is the best practice here, if an item is not yet in the local store?

Lets say you are 'requesting' an item that is not yet in the local store (but would be available from the api), would you automatically try to retrieve it from the api before returning empty/an error?

Is there any best practice on how to implement this? It seems to be a pretty common use case.

Our should you just try to always load the whole data-set (or at least a minimal version) of it?

Also: what if the items change all the time (other users). Is there even a point in having those items in the store locally, if you need to request it again everytime you want to see its details to not get an outdated version?

Thanks